# PDO query to mysql with a numeric name for mysql column. How to execute properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a field in mysql table called: "1"  which is a number...

MY PDO CODE IS:

```
$category = 1;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM account where :category = '1'");
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $category, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

It doesn't work because in mysql I have to use:

```
SELECT * FROM account where `1` = '1';
```

and not:

```
SELECT * FROM account where 1 = '1';
```

how can I do that with my PDO ?

thx

Comment: The column is actually named `1`? Wow, confusing. In PDO, you _still_ use backticks to quote it `WHERE \`1\` = :category` Nothing is different from any other MySQL client.

Comment: Why on earth do you need to name your columns as numbers? if you really need to why not use one?

Comment: Or are you trying to bind `:category` in place of the _column_ named `1` rather than the _value_ 1?  If that is the case, you _cannot_ do it because you can't bind a column name as a parameter in PDO.

Comment: I tried this `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM account where `:category` = '1'");`    but it doesn't work either

Comment: So you are hoping to bind `:category` to name the column `1`... that is not possible.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter -- if the value comes from user input, you must validate it against an array of acceptable values. But if you set it in code with `$category = 1` and know it to be a safe value, then there is no need for a parameter and you can use `\`$category\` = '1'` with the variable directly.

Comment: Smells like a terrible database design. Category values as columns...

Comment: @michel-berkowski .. yes, this is what I was trying to do... but I could do it with the old php api... like this:  `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account where ``".$category."``` = '1' order by rand()")or die(mysql_error());}`  isn't there a way with PDO to do something similar?

Comment: @user3011784 Where does the variable `$category` originate? Does it come from user input? If you validate it to be a known integer column name, you can do it exactly like you did with `mysql_query()` using `$pdo->query()`

Comment: @michel-berkowski the variable comes from a drop down selection... if first item, value = 1, if second item, value = 2...etc...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski so would this work:  `$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM account where ``".$category."`` = '1' order by rand()", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` ?

Comment: @user3011784 Hang on for an answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO [does not permit you to use a bound parameter as a column or table identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) so it is not directly possible to use `:category` with `prepare()/execute()` and successfully substitute a numeric column name.

But if you can safely validate the numeric column name from your dropdown menu to prove it is in an acceptable range and is indeed an integer, then it is safe to use a variable in the query. You will need to quote it with backticks as you are already aware.

Validate it with an expression like `ctype_digit($category)` or `preg_match('/^\d+$/', $category)` and test that it is in the range of integers for which you have column names.

```
// Validate $cateogry
// Assuming it came from $_POST['category']
$category = isset($_POST['category']) ? $_POST['category'] : null;

// And assuming the possible range was 1 - 4
// Ensure the input value was an integer with ctype_digit()
if (ctype_digit($category) && $category >= 1 && $category <=4) {
  // Execute the query with a backtick-quoted $category
  // Since you aren't going to bind any params, you can skip the overhead of
  // prepare()/bindParam()/execute() and just call query() instead
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM account where `$category` = '1' order by rand()");
  if ($result) {
    // Fetch rows and do whatever you planned with them
    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
}
else {
  // Invalid value, don't perform your query, show an error, etc....
}
```

If you don't have the ctype extension installed (you probably do) then use the `preg_match()` example instead.

One other possibility would be to use `in_array()` with `range()` assuming your columns are named sequentially. I maybe prefer this one to either of the other validation options:

```
if (in_array($category, range(1, 4))) {
  // $category is valid - go ahead and query with it as above
}
```

As mentioned in the comment thread, if you are in any position to *change* this column naming scheme, it would be a good idea to do so. This is just downright confusing.  If you are accepting input for the column name though, it still doesn't change the fact that you can't use a PDO parameter for it. You still need to validate it against an array of possible column names.